# Is there a way to get full 2D mouse precision with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

High performance 2D Mice these days have 1000Hz sampling rate and 10000+ DPI. Inferring mouse input by checking what pixel the pointer is on isn't receiving the maximum precision of these 2D Mice. Is there a way that JavaScript can tap into the full precision?

While it wouldn't be practical for JavaScript itself to collect all 1000 samples every second, the browser could collect them all. Then when JavaScript queries, say every 16ms, the browser could give it the average of the last 16 samples. Like GamePad API it could give axis data directly without having to infer.

Why? WebGL games and simulations could really take advantage of it.

Comment: I'm not sure what precision you *need* beyond "the mouse is on *this* pixel,* since that's the finest resolution of use, since the mouse pointer can't be drawn in sub-pixel units.

Comment: I should have specified WebGL 3D games. Pointer drawing is only like 60hz, while high performance mouse sampling is 1000hz. Screens are typically less than 2000 pixels across, yet high performance mice are 10000 dpi.

Comment: But again, how does it help? This may be a massive improvement - if it's possible - I just don't see how knowing where the mouse is, with greater accuracy, helps given that the medium in which it's displayed can't display that pointer any more accurately, or convey movements more specifically, than it already does. This seems less of a useful resource and more an inevitable means of consuming yet more CPU time.

Comment: "...given that the medium in which it's displayed can't display that pointer any more accurately..."
While that may be true for 2D, it's not for 3D. Moving the pointer from center to side is usually 1000 pixels. Say you map that to a 180deg turn, that's a 0.18 degree jump per pixel, well at fov 60 0.18 deg is quite a few pixels (depends how close to center.) I want each jump to be 1 pixel.

Answer (score 1):

I have at least a partial answer. Apparently you can with pointer lock
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/pointerlock/intro/
"Get access to raw mouse data including relative mouse movements"
The Quake3 map link has a good demonstration http://media.tojicode.com/q3bsp/

However is it also possible to get raw mouse data without having to perform pointer lock? For cases where you want to go in and out of the window constantly, though I suppose it's not a big deal to press escape to unlock the pointer.

UPDATE: http://www.w3.org/TR/pointerlock/#high-resolution-deltas-high-frequency-updates
I'm not sure about update frequency, though this article hasn't been updated recently. While JavaScript may only sample at say every 16ms, it should be able to obtain an average of the last 16 samples from a 1000hz mouse. As I find out more details I'll post it here.